# using ionicons 5 in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionicons

I want to use **ionicons 5** in my **vue.js** project.

```
<ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
```

If I use:

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
```

every thing works fine **but** I want to use it just like any other npm package and bundle it with my other modules using webpack.

What should I do?

What is the correct way of using ionicons 5 in a vue.js project (**without using script tag & linking to cdn**)

**font awesome** provides an official vue.js component:

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs